# Can you have two PDO connection instances with two different usernames (with different privileges) that access the same database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection

I am new to PHP/MySQL so be kind.

I would like to ensure a reader (Guest) of a page only has "read, create, update" privileges within the MySQL user. This user does not need to login at this point.

In addition, on login only I would like my admin (Admin) to have the above plus "delete".

Suggestion 1:
Someone suggested having an initial PDO connection for the Guest user which connects with the initial privileges, and then upon login switching to another PDO connection. This second connection would include more privileges. Is this an approach used?

Suggestion 2:
If that is not the case, is it best to create the PDO connection with all privileges but manage through an assigned "role"? This role would be assigned when the user is created.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes you can. However, "Suggestion 2" is how it is done in 100% of web applications

Comment: As above -option 2, the ONLY time I have seen anything more is where a separate admin application is there with elevated privileges.

Comment: Thank you both! You've put my mind at ease. Much appreciated!